# Stop doing e.preventDefault(); on second click?

Tags: jquery

For the life of me, I can't seem to be able to crack this.  I'm fairly novice with jQuery, but I'm trying to simply:

The link I'm acting on directs to */mypagename*

1. On first click of a.nav_hidepanel, fire animation on `#panel`, but DON'T allow the link to function as usual.  However, add a replacement class of `.nav_returnlink` so that we can target it the next time
2. Now, the second time this link is clicked, it has a different class, so we want to allow it to function as usual and send the user to /mypagename

Having no problems disabling the link, but the `return true;` just doesn't seem to work!  Am I missing something obvious?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.nav_hidepanel").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#panel").animate({marginLeft:"-547px"}, 500 );
        $(this).removeClass('nav_hidepanel');
        $(this).addClass('nav_returnlink');
    });

    $("a.nav_returnlink").click(function(){
        return true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the element will have the `nav_returnlink` class after the first click, simply check for it's presence:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.nav_hidepanel").click(function(e){
        //This will return true after the first click 
        //and preventDefault won't be called.
        if(!$(this).hasClass('nav_returnlink'))
            e.preventDefault();

        $("#panel").animate({marginLeft:"-547px"}, 500 );
        $(this).removeClass('nav_hidepanel');
        $(this).addClass('nav_returnlink');
    });
});
```

Comment: Definitely more streamlined than the code I was plugging away with :)  I understand why you've been more specific about when to prevent the default action too.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a short explanation of why you code did not work:

- You bind a click event on a.nav_hidepanel with a preventDefault **this is ok**
- You bind a click event to an element a.nav_returnlink which does not exist at that time. **this is a problem**
- On your first click callback you call e.preventDefault(), as this click event is never unbound, this link will never execute it's default action. **this is again a problem**

Here is a possible solution

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.nav_hidepanel").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#panel").animate({marginLeft:"-547px"}, 500 );
    $(this).removeClass('nav_hidepanel');
    $(this).addClass('nav_returnlink');
    $(this).unbind('click'); //unbind the click event so this is not called again
  });
  $("a.nav_returnlink").live(function(){ //use a live event to bind to this element, that is available in the future
      return true;
  });
});
```

Another solution could be to bind the new click event in the first callback:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.nav_hidepanel").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#panel").animate({marginLeft:"-547px"}, 500 );
    $(this).removeClass('nav_hidepanel');
    $(this).addClass('nav_returnlink');
    $(this).unbind('click');

    $(this).click(function(){
        //do whatever you like to do
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try add click event in live functtion with jquery

```
$("a.nav_returnlink").live("click",function(){
   return true;
});
```

Comment: this would also solve the problem... however i still think the proper approach would be to remove the event handler after you are done using it.

Answer (score 1):

**Why not use a counter instead?**

```
var clickCount = 0;
$("a.nav_hidepanel").click(function(e){
    if(clickCount == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#panel").animate({marginLeft:"-547px"}, 500 );
    }
    clickCount++;
});
```

Comment: I assumed that using a counter was a little bit unwieldy?

Comment: @user9980 Yeah I guess you could use a boolean instead but seems you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you could always just unbind the event handler....

```
var clickCancel = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).unbind("click",clickCancel);
    $("#panel").animate({marginLeft:"-547px"}, 500 );// you add your animation in this function, it will only be called on  the first click..

};
$("a.nav_hidepanel").bind("click", clickCancel);
```

[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ZeeBn/)